# Show that $|f(z)|=\phi(x)\psi(y)$, $x+iy \in D$ implies that $f(z)=e^{az^2+bz+c}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $f$ is an analytic fuction in a domain $D$ and that it does not assume non-negative real values ​​in $D$. Show that $|f(z)|=\phi(x)\psi(y)$, $x+iy \in D$ implies that

$f(z)=e^{az^2+bz+c}$

where $a$ is a real constant and $b, c$ are complex constants.
I tried to use the equations of Cauchy riemann, but I could not develop anything. Someone has a better tip

Answer (score 2):

There is an analytic branch of logarithm, say $L$ on $\mathbb C \setminus [0,\infty)$. Let $g=L\circ f$. Then $g$ is analytic and $\Re g(z)= log |f(z)|=log \, \phi (x)+log \, \psi (y)$. Also, $\Re g$ is harmonic. Calculating the Laplacian we get $(log \, \phi (x))''+(log \, \psi (y))''=0$. This can only happen if both the terms are constants. Hence $log \, \phi (x) $ and $log \, \psi (y)$ are both quadratic functions. It is now easy to complete the proof. [ Note that if $ax^{2}+bx+c+a'y^{2}+b'y+c'$ is harmonic then $a=-a'$ so $ax^{2}+a'y^{2}=a\Re z^{2}$. I leave the rest of the argument to you].

Comment: Why the real part of the composition is only $|f(z)|$?
Should not a cosine appear?

Comment: If we transform $g(x)$ into the polar form

Comment: @RicardoFreire $e^{L(z)}=z$. So $|z|=|e^{L(z)}|=e^{\Re L(z)}$ which gives $\Re L(z)=log\, |z|$.

Comment: okay. But where did that come from? $log(\phi(x))''+log(\psi(x))''=0$ 
what guarantees that this laplacian is zero?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: what guarantees that this laplacian $log(\phi(x))''+log(\psi(x))''=0$  is zero?

Comment: Or rather why $\Re g(z)$ is harmonic?

Comment: Real part of an analytic function is harmonic. So $\Re log \, g$ is harmonic. Now calculate the Laplacian of $\Re log \, g=log\ \phi (x)+\log \psi (y)$.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this result.